# mysql join limit with two tables

Tags: mysql, join

i have two tables like this ->

```
Categories
-----------
id      name
---------
1 -->      a
2    -->   b
3    -->   c



    Messages
    ------------
    id        catid    message
    ---------------------------
    1   -->      1   -->     aa
    2      -->   1   -->     bb
    3        --> 1   -->     cc
    4        --> 2   -->     dd
    5        --> 3    -->    ee
    6        --> 3    -->    ff

    i want to join the tables for get FIRST message from messages table,
```

i want query result like this ->

```
-------------------------------
id         name       message
1          a          aa
2          b          dd
3          c          ee
```

i found a code

```
select * from categories c, items i
    -> where i.categoryid = c.id
    -> group by c.id;
```

but there isn't any ORDER BY procedure

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.*, i.*
FROM categories c
JOIN items i ON (i.categoryid = c.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN items i2 ON (i2.categoryid = c.id 
  AND (i.message > i2.message OR i.message = i2.message AND i.id > i2.id))
WHERE i2.categoryid IS NULL
ORDER BY c.id;
```

This tends to perform better on MySQL, since MySQL does so badly at `GROUP BY` queries.

Answer (score 0):

MySql will always return the first record from 2nd table if you group by the first one.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.message FROM Categories a, Messages b WHERE b.catid = a.id GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: That's not a documented policy of MySQL, it just happens to be true in the current version.  I wouldn't recommend relying on this being true for all storage engines or in future versions.

Comment: Or, indeed, over some kinds of database export/import. If you honestly don't care whether you get message aa, bb or cc you can get away with this query. But an ANSI-compliant DBMS would still complain.